# Why is this 'WHEN THEN' SQL query not returning the expected result?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008, case-when

Can somebody please explain why this query brings up `NULL` as result however I set the @wnum variable? I have tried all possible and different operators/commands I can think of.

Result should be @wnum3=52, @wnum4=53 if @wnum=49 or
@wnum3=1, @wnum4=2 if @wnum=50

```
DECLARE @wnum AS int SET @wnum = 49
DECLARE @wnum3 AS int
DECLARE @wnum4 AS int

SELECT @wnum3
SET @wnum3 = CASE WHEN @wnum >=50 THEN 1 WHEN @wnum <50 THEN @wnum+3 
END

SELECT@wnum4
SET @wnum4 = CASE WHEN @wnum >=50 THEN 2 WHEN @wnum <50 THEN @wnum+4 
END
```

Answer (score 3):

You are selecting before setting the variable. Swap the `SET` & `SELECT` lines around:

```
DECLARE @wnum AS int SET @wnum = 49
DECLARE @wnum3 AS int
DECLARE @wnum4 AS int

SET @wnum3 = CASE WHEN @wnum >=50 THEN 1 WHEN @wnum <50 THEN @wnum+3 END
SELECT @wnum3

SET @wnum4 = CASE WHEN @wnum >=50 THEN 2 WHEN @wnum <50 THEN @wnum+4 END
SELECT @wnum4
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to always use SET for setting the value for a single variable. It is ANSI standard. For setting multiple variables, you can use SELECT, which is a TSQL extension.

Once you set the value only you can select the value. Otherwise, you will get NULL value.

If you have got proper formatting, this confusion will not arise. I have re-written the code with SET as per ANSI standard. Now, you will get clarity on what is happening.

```sql
-- Declarations
DECLARE @wnum AS INT;
DECLARE @wnum3 AS INT;
DECLARE @wnum4 AS INT;

--Initializations
SET @wnum = 49;

-- Logic 

SET @wnum3 = (SELECT CASE WHEN @wnum >=50 THEN 1 WHEN @wnum <50 THEN @wnum+3 END);

SELECT @wnum3;

SET @wnum4 = (SELECT CASE WHEN @wnum >=50 THEN 2 WHEN @wnum <50 THEN @wnum+4 END);

SELECT @wnum4;
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try below query for the solution of your problem.

```
DECLARE @wnum AS INT

SET @wnum = 49

DECLARE @wnum3 AS INT
DECLARE @wnum4 AS INT

SELECT @wnum3 = CASE 
        WHEN @wnum >= 50
            THEN 1
        WHEN @wnum < 50
            THEN @wnum + 3
        END

SELECT @wnum3

SELECT @wnum4 = CASE 
        WHEN @wnum >= 50
            THEN 2
        WHEN @wnum < 50
            THEN @wnum + 4
        END
SELECT @wnum4
```

Answer (score -1):

Select query is written before assignment, Please modify your query as follows : -

```
DECLARE @wnum AS int SET @wnum = 49
DECLARE @wnum3 AS int
DECLARE @wnum4 AS int

SELECT @wnum3
SET @wnum3 = CASE WHEN @wnum >=50 THEN 1 WHEN @wnum <50 THEN @wnum+3 END
SELECT @wnum3
```